# Error MVC org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors with array

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model, javabeans

Hi I try pass an array in a bean from jsp to java.

```
@ModelAttribute("areasActividadAdminBean")AreasActividadAdminBean areasActividadAdminBean

Agrupacion[] listaAgrupaciones = x;

model.addAttribute("areasActividadAdminBean",areasActividadAdminBean);
```

In JSP i have this:

```
<form:form commandName="areasActividadAdminBean" .....>

<form:hidden path="listaAgrupaciones"/>

<input type="submit" value="Button"/>
```

But I get this error:

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'areasActividadAdminBean' on field 'listaAgrupaciones': rejected value
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure the BindingResult method parameter follows the Object that you are binding to. Example

```
public String add(@Valid DomainObject domainObj, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
```